# Convert Groovy Map to String in Yaml format

Tags: groovy, yaml, snakeyaml

I am using snakeYaml to convert a **String** in YAML format **to** Groovy **Map**.

```
@Grab(group='org.yaml', module='snakeyaml', version='1.17')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

Yaml yaml = new Yaml()

Map config = yaml.load(new File('config.yaml').text)
```

I want to reach now the opposite : Given a Groovy **Map**, i want to convert it to **String** in YAML format WITHOUT WRITING THE STRING in a FILE.

I found `groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder`. However, the groovy compiler of the environment is old and this class is not found.

Ideally, the same lib (snakeYaml) can handle the opposite case. But no way to get it work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write to a YAML file using SnakeYaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949505/how-do-i-write-to-a-yaml-file-using-snakeyaml)

Comment: Not the same. I want to get the String in Yaml format without writing the String in a text

Comment: Sorry, but maybe you have to be more explicit - I don't see how `yaml.dump([a: 1])` is not what you are asking? "Encode a  map datastrcuture to YAML"

Comment: Agree with @cfrick above, the signature of dump is `String dump(Object data)`, i.e. the [dump method](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml.html#dump-java.lang.Object-) returns a `String` which I believe is what you are asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes `yaml.dump()` is the answer

```
Map config = [kind: 'Pod', metadata:[name: app]]

Yaml yaml = new Yaml()

assert yaml.dump(config) == '''kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app
'''
```